# Why am I getting Max execution steps exceeded (200) | Exception of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, execution, jint

I have written a function that converts a bit mask value that I am sending to a webpage and then using it to show a user where and how many sensors that in place. It is pretty basic, it is taking a number, and using bitwise maths to check where a `1` is and then storing that position number from an array to a string to be returned.

But I am getting an error when I give values:

> `bit` >= 30 and `TEMPmax` = 9

when I use those values I get:

```
Max execution steps exceeded (200) | Exception of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.
```

But if I change `TEMPmax = 5` and `bit` = 30, I don't get any errors.
I am using this as a temporary fix, but from the code you can see it can have up to eight different positions.

What I don't understand is why I exceed the execution steps, the `for()` loop is only happening 9 times and the stuff in the `if` loop, and possibly I presume there are other things happening(enlighten me please).

**Questions:**

- Why would I be exceeding my Max execution steps?
- How could I fix this or make it efficient?
- How can I determine how many execution steps happen in the code?

---

This is the code I wrote(self explanatory):

```
var all = ["pos1", "pos2", "pos3", "pos4", "pos5", "pos6", "pos7", "pos8"]; //temp sensors possible
var TEMPmax = 9;
var text = "";  //value to return
var bit = fields.get('TotalTempsensors', 0); // none


if(bit > 1){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < TEMPmax; i++){

        if((bit & (1 << i))){

            text += all[i - 1];
            text += ",";

        }   
    }
}
else{
    text = "ERROR";
}

return text;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using an old version of Jint. Please find the latest at https://github.com/sebastienros/jint or on Nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jint/